# jQuery - Halt credit card process to display popUp question

Tags: jquery, forms

Could someone tell me if its possible and if so put me on the right path on how to do so?

We have a checkout form to process credit card transaction.

On click of the submit button, I would like to check if a specific option is checked.
If its checked, then go ahead and process credit card.
If not checked, I would like to halt the process and display a pop up asking the user if they are sure they about the option.

Is it possible with jQuery to halt the submitting of the form until this pop up is closed?

Comment: i see on the jQuery site the function submit(). I dont think this will help me though because I am not really trying to submit the form or not submit the form, I really kind of want to pause the submit and give the user a last chance to check the box.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. Add an onclick event to your submit button. If the onlcick returns false, the form will not submit. What you can do here is check for the option, and if you are going to submit, return true. If you need to do the popup first, don't return from the function until the popup is done (and then return true). This also allows you to cancel submission if you need to (user decideds during the popup not to submit) by returning false.

```
<input type="submit" value="submit" onclick="return popupcheck()" />
```

I'm not sure what kind of popup you are using, but here is some suggested pseudocode for the javascript:

```
function popupcheck(){
    if(optionischecked){
       return true    //the form will submit
    }
    create/show popup
    return false      //the form will not submit (call popupisdone when the popup is done)
}
function popupisdone(){ //wire this up to be called when the popup is done
    $("#ccform").submit()  //unless there is some sort of cancel submit option in the popup
}
```

Comment: Don't know if that will work since the function will return with void as soon as the popup is created. I think it would be better to call $('#theForm').submit() when they click yes, and always return false in the onclick function creating the dialog

Comment: That method would be better than having the function busy wait until the popup is done. Editing now to reflect that

Comment: This looks great, thank you for the help Greg. Ill plug it up and do my best to learn from it.